# Dialogflow human takeover

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a bot for a bank using Dialogflow. I wanted to keep am option to talk with a Customer representative. If a customer wanted to talk with a customer representative, the bot Should stop and the customer representative starts the chat with a customer. How it is possible In Dialogflow.

Answer (score 2):

That option is only available by creating your own **custom implementation**.

Check out this example [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs)

It can also depend on the channel you are using For example, if you are using Facebook Messenger you can achieve that using the [Handover Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/) in your custom implementation

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible because dialogflow does not provide any web interface to achieve this, but in dialogflow usually the "input.unknown" action used to deliver a conversation to a human. Default fallback intent is triggered and the associated action is added to the response, and you also need to write a logic to what bot should do after that.

But if you're looking to avoid this hassle, I 'd suggest you use a chat widget tool like [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/), which provides a dashboard UI as well as a chat widget. In fact, they also have a pre-built rich message template to create menu options to deliver a conversation to a human agent. Please check this [link](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/chatbot-human-handoff/) for more info

PS: I work for kommunicate

Answer (score 0):

Another option is if you have the phone gateway integration enabled, Click 'Add Response' under the DIALOGFLOW PHONE GATEWAY tab and just select Transfer Call.